# openpyxl - get real values of cells when create a list

Tags: python, list, openpyxl

I have this code to read a .xlsx file :

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
       
content = list(ws1.iter_rows(values_only=True)
```

But the format of datas inside the `content` list contains some `'None'` and some `'datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 21, 0, 0)'`

How can I do the same to be sure the content list contains only real values inside ?
So None would be '' and  datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 21, 0, 0) would be a real date.

I have tried

```
content = list(str(ws1.iter_rows(values_only=True))
```

but it's not working

Thanks

Comment: Openpyxl does provide real values. `""` is an empty string, but `None` is an empty cell and `datetimes()` are real dates in Python.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks for the clarification. I just needed a way to translate those into a list with str values

Comment: No magic bullet: it's worth taking the time to decide the string representation for each type. Easy enough to do.

Comment: Yes certainly, once somebody explains it to you ;-) I'm kind of a noob in Python BTW. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

content = [
    [str(cell) if cell is not None and not isinstance(cell, datetime) else '' if cell is None else cell.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for cell in row]
    for row in ws1.iter_rows(values_only=True)
]

# Now 'content' contains only real values with None replaced by '' and datetime objects converted to strings
print(content)
```

Ensure that the datetime module is imported correctly with from datetime import datetime

```
for row in ws1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    print([type(cell) for cell in row])
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposition, it's working for the Nones but not for the datetime objects

Comment: @Nico44044, I have modify the code. Please check.

Comment: I have this : TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: @Nico44044, I have adjusted the code pls try now.

Comment: Works (sorry I imported datetime the wrong way).